# How do I webscrape .dpbox table using selectorgadget with R (rvest)?

Tags: html, css, r, web-scraping, rvest

I've been trying to webscrape data from a specific website using selectorgadget in R. For example, I successfully webscraped from http://www.dotabuff.com/heroes/abaddon/matchups before. Usually, I just click on the tables I want using the selectorgadget Chrome extension and put the CSS Selection result into the code as follows.

```
urlx <- "http://www.dotabuff.com/heroes/abaddon/matchups"
rawData <- html_text(html_nodes(read_html(urlx),"td:nth-child(4) , td:nth-child(3), .cell-xlarge"))
```

In this case, the html_nodes function does return a whole bunch of nodes (340)

```
{xml_nodeset (340)}
```

However, when I try to webscrape off http://www.dotapicker.com/heroes/Abaddon using selectorgadget, which turns out to be this code:

```
urlx <- "http://www.dotapicker.com/heroes/abaddon"
rawData <- html_text(html_nodes(read_html(urlx),".ng-scope:nth-child(1) .ng-scope .ng-binding"))
```

Unfortunately, no nodes actually show up after the html_nodes function is called, and I get the result

```
{xml_nodeset (0)}
```

I feel like this has something to do with the nesting of the table in a drop down box (compared to previously, the table was right on the webpage itself) but I'm not sure how to get around it.

Thank you and I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this page load dynamically some data using XHR. In Chrome you can check that by going to inspect and then the network tab. If you do this, you will see that there are a number of json files that are being loaded. You can scrape directly those json files and then parse them to extract the info you need. Here is a quick example:

```r
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

heroinfo_json <- GET("http://www.dotapicker.com/assets/json/data/heroinfo.json")
heroinfo_flat <- fromJSON(content(heroinfo_json, type = "text"))
#> No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.

winrates_json <- GET("http://www.dotapicker.com/assets/dynamic/winrates10d.json")
winrates_flat <- fromJSON(content(winrates_json, type = "text"))
#> No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.
```